# Как вычислить все возведения в степень без повторов результатов?

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, математика

Как вычислить все возведения в степень с **x_min** ^ **y_min** по **x_max** ^ **y_max** без повторов результатов?

Например:

- **x2** ^ **x8** = **z**
- ...
- **x85** ^ **y23** = **p**
- ...
- но **x85** ^ **y28** = **z** !

Как видно, результат **z** повторяется у разных вычислений.

Kаким образом можно пропускать *все следующие вычисления* при условии, что **сравнивать** с ранее вычисленными результатами **не допустимо**?

```
# code python 3
min_x, max_x = 5, 127
min_y, max_y = 2, 250
result = ''
for x in range(min_x, max_x):
    for y in range(min_y, max_y):
        result += str(x ** y)
```

Comment: почему недопустимо? откуда такие требования? И да, что именно запрещено делать?

Comment: Потому что это занимает **очень долгое время**. Так как значения x и y могут быть намного больше, чем 1 000, и все вычисленные результаты сохраняются в переменную _result_.

Comment: вопрос только в производительности?

Comment: И да и нет. Я так же не хочу тратить лишнюю память, потому что планируется использовать как минимум 2 гигабайта только для хранения переменой result.
Разве нет какой нибудь мат формулы для решения данной проблемы? Просто представьте сколько по времени искать подстроку хотя бы в 300МБ.. :)

Comment: ну 300 метров это немного) вычислите всё, отсортируйте и удалите дубликаты)

Comment: Я не буду вдаваться в дискуссию, извините. Есть задача с условием, которое зависит от ряда прочих обстоятельств. Все их здесь я не могу привести, к сожалению. Что ж, буду ждать решения. Спасибо за отклик :)

Comment: как на счет решения в pandas module?  будет гарантированно быстрее чем в циклах

Comment: MaxU, вы бы могли бы уточнить, что именно имеете ввиду и написать пример кода в ответ, чтобы если он подходит, я смог его отметить?

Comment: @sergus, я думаю numpy должно быть достаточно для решения этой задачи. Проверьте мой ответ - это то что вам нужно или нет?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:** - только что проверил с вашими числами - Python "занимал" около 1GB памяти, `timing` я обновил для ваших чисел

```
In [105]: x = np.arange(5, 8800, dtype=np.uint64)

In [106]: y = np.arange(2, 8250, dtype=np.uint64)

In [107]: r = np.unique(np.array([np.power(x, np.repeat([pw], len(x))) for pw in np.nditer(y)]))

In [108]: len(''.join(r.astype(str)))
Out[108]: 457656

In [109]: %timeit np.unique(np.array([np.power(x, np.repeat([pw], len(x))) for pw in np.nditer(y)]))
1 loop, best of 3: 11.3 s per loop

In [115]: np.version.version
Out[115]: '1.10.4'
```

numpy solution:

```
x = np.arange(5, 127, dtype=np.uint64)
y = np.arange(2, 250, dtype=np.uint64)

r = np.unique(np.array([np.power(x, np.repeat([pw], len(x))) for pw in np.nditer(y)]))

# чтобы сэкономить память записываем строку в `r`
r = ''.join(r.astype(str))
print(r)
```

Timing для 5000 x 5000 массива:

```
In [102]: %timeit np.unique(np.array([np.power(x, np.repeat([pw], len(x))) for pw in np.nditer(y)]))
1 loop, best of 3: 3.89 s per loop

In [103]: x.shape
Out[103]: (4995,)

In [104]: y.shape
Out[104]: (4998,)
```

Comment: С маленькими числами работает действительно быстро! Но вот с такими данными вообще вылетает momory error: x = np.arange(5, 8800, dtype=np.uint64); y = np.arange(2, 8250, dtype=np.uint64)
Как-нибудь можно избежать это?) Памяти хоть за глаза, может быть это ошибка numpy?

Comment: я немного поменял решение - `np.repeat()` вместо `np.array()` - это должно экономить память. Какая у вас версия numpy?

Comment: Проверил новый код, процесс питона доходит до 750МБ и падает на той же ошибке. PyCharm last upd, Python 3.4.4 x32, numpy 1.11.0

Comment: `Памяти хоть за глаза` и `x32` - не совсем совместимые понятия ;) Попробуйте закрыть лишние приложения, включая IDEA и запустить скрипт из ком. строки

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что свои честные 3 ГБ он должен отработать :)
Запустил скрипт из CMD на python 2.7, но ничего не закрывал и сработало! В 3.x откатился на 1.10.4 но по прежнему ошибка:
File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py", line 176, in unique
    ar = np.asanyarray(ar).flatten()
MemoryError

Comment: я думаю дело не в версии 1.11.0 - это стабильная версия, я просто ее пока не ставлю из-за `pandas`.  Windows  у вас 64-битный?

Comment: Да, Win8.1 x64 Single Language. Сейчас проверил на Python 3.4 x64 работает стабильно - занял не больше 870 МБ, отработал и выдал длину строки с результатом 457656.

Comment: я думаю стоит перейти на 64-битный Python + 64-битные модули (например numpy, pandas, etc.) и иметь возможность использовать больше памяти   - т.к. разница в производительности между векторизированным подходом (numpy, scipy, pandas) и обычными (for loop, list comprehension) будет отличаться на порядки.

Comment: Благодарю за совет, на своей машине запросто, но данный скрипт должен гарантировать работу и на x32 машинах. Думаю в дальнейшем я просто разделю числа на части и буду сохранять их на диск. Если не найдётся другого решения конечно. Я ещё немного подожду ответов и если более выгодного, чем ваш не окажется, закрою вопрос.

Comment: вчера не заметил, ошибки numpy:
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  r = np.unique(np.array([np.power(x, np.repeat([pw], len(x))) for pw in np.nditer(y)])); RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power
  r = np.unique(np.array([np.power(x, np.repeat([pw], len(x))) for pw in np.nditer(y)])). Как бы это поправить? :)

Comment: @sergus, по-моему никак, максимально возможное np.uint64 число в numpy это - `np.iinfo(np.uint64) - 18446744073709551615` и это меньше чем `10^20`.  Т.е. для вашей задачи `numpy` совершенно не подходит

Comment: благодарю за разъяснения! Жаль, питон выбирал именно из-за утверждения, что он работает с ооочень большими числами :)

Comment: @sergus, Python работает, а вот numpy - нет.

Comment: Ага, теперь ясно, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Так как основная проблема автора - недостаток ресурсов (или все-таки какая-то абстрактная задачка?), то можно предложить такой выход из положения: не генерировать сразу все-все значения, а написать генератор, который будет выдавать значения тогда, когда это будет нужно. Эти значения ведь все равно где-то будут использованы - будь то запись в файл или какие-нибудь операции над получившимся вектором - и использованы они будут по-одному.

```
def give_me_square():
    first = range(5, 8800)
    second = range(2, 9000)
    for i in first:
        for j in second:
            yield i**j

counter = 0
total = 8800*9000

for square in give_me_square():
    if counter % 10000 == 0:
        print(counter, "of", total)
    counter += 1
```

Работает совсем нешустро, зато память не ест. Такой генератор можно сделать асинхронным, можно отдать его в multiprocessing.Pool.map, много чего можно придумать.

Comment: кстати - это надежный вариант. только надо добавить фильтрацию на дупликаты

Comment: да, такой вариант я как раз и отбросил из за долгого поиска и удаления дубликатов :)
Мне как раз нужны сразу все значения, они записываться в файл не будут, хранятся только в виртуальной памяти

Comment: @sergus, как так сразу все? Как вы собираетесь в дальнейшем использовать список всех неповторяющихся значений? Если хранить все эти числа - неважно как именно, то можно попрощаться с мечтой о том, что все влезет в память. Сложность по памяти - O(n*m) - это, во-первых. Во-вторых, 1000 в степени 1000 - это огромное число - намного больше чем int64 (2**64). При вычислении такого числа используется уже арифметика на строках - а это совсем другой разговор по части быстродействия и памяти, потому что "дешево" работать с такими числами не получится, ну никак.

Comment: да, "слона то я и не заметил"... `numpy` - не сможет правильно посчитать 1000^1000. Вот пример: `x = np.array([1000], dtype=np.uint64); np.power(x, x)` Output: `array([9223372036854775808], dtype=uint64)`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Мне требуется произвести поиск чисел в этом массиве. Как писал выше в комментариях, я думаю разделять на порции и проверять подстроку. Эх досада какая. То есть сейчас скрипт не вычисляет 1000^1000? Что посоветуете в таком случае? Я мало знаком с numpy, не пинайте сильно :)

Comment: Более того, я посчитал 2000*2000 на 64 битной машине с дупликатами (на 32 бита не влазит - шибко жирно). Так вот дупликатов там 52158, или же чуть больше 1.3%. Стоит ли из-за одного процента голову ломать? 2000*2000 посчиталось за 2 минуты, но надо понимать, что с возрастанием чисел процес будет замедляться и жрать память в таких количествах, что не приснится в страшном сне.

Comment: @sergus, если не секрет, в чем состоит бОльшая задача? Зачем хранить это в строке? Может есть другой алгоритм / подход?

Comment: Мне нравится ваш настрой ;)  Видимо стоит изменить вообще подход к задаче. А что если по заданной подстроке в числовом виде, найти его x^y? Задача изначальная состояла в поиске подстроки в *массиве числовых данных* но с указателями, что бы в последствии можно было на него ссылаться, разумеется из памяти всё удалялось, а оставалось запись вида "position,len,x^y,x^y"

Comment: @sergus, а если "числовые" данные (результаты возведения в степень) хранить скажем в SQLite и искать в DB?

Comment: @MaxU, Я уже обдумывал этот вариант, но честно говоря не хотелось бы прибегать к такому (из-за времени)) Хотя сам понимаю, что отчасти всё было бы проще с бд провернуть, чем искать в оперативке. Зачем удалили второй update? Я его только, что проверил, всё исправно работает!

Comment: @sergus, `update2` - работает не правильно, т.к. он учитывет только повторы, но не учитывет одинаковые результаты, например `8**2` и `2**6`, для этого понадобилось бы факторизировать все числа

Comment: @sergus, мне все не дает покоя ваша задача... ;) все еще пытаюсь понять зачем вам проверять является ли число результатом возведения в степень `x^y` - у меня складывется ощущение, что вы численно проверяете [теорему Ферма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)? :)

Comment: @MaxU, на самом деле вы правы, именно этим я и занимаюсь. Пытаюсь найти своё решение :D

Comment: @sergus, когда найдете эффективное решение - дайте знать пожалуйста. Можно будет эффективно ломать RSA шифрование ;)

Comment: @MaxU, Хе-хе, с у довольствием!! :)